# Should "at" or "to" be used in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Should "at" or "to" be used in the following sentence?

> You can send me an email with any inquiries to: email@website.com.

or

> You can send me an email with any inquiries at: email@website.com.

Why is one sentence is most correct?

Comment: No authority here, but common usage seems to be "*to e-mail address*" and "*at website URL*".

Comment: To it and at it. At it and to it. You've got to tune your attitude in. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4jtculWHk